# Wordpress website displaying blank

Tags: plugins, wordpress, syntax-error

May be there is some error in plugin, due to this my website displaying blank.
But when I comment this code in wp-setting.php then display but without plugins

```
foreach ( wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins() as $plugin ) {
    wp_register_plugin_realpath( $plugin );
    include_once( $plugin );
}
```

What problem may be ?

Answer (score 0):

First start by logging in to your FTP, going into wp-content folder and renaming the "plugins" folder to "plugins.old"...then try logging on to the site.

If that works, go into the dashboard and click plugins (you'll see that they've all been deactivated). Rename your plugins folder back to plugins and one by one, activate them. If the site crashes, that plugin that you just activated is bad.